# using ansible to fetch from remote src path to the local same path from a couple hosts

Tags: ansible

Using `copy` or `fetch`, the newer host directory covers the earlier ones. I would like to have each located under the same local path, maybe host specific info used as suffix.

```
ansile aid -m copy -a "src=/data/logs/app dest=logs remote_src=true"
```

ansible is used for a bunch of machines, there should be a way to distinguish `copy` for each machine.

Comment: [edit] the question and post the expected result. Make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**copy**

*`remote_src=true`* does what it says. It takes *src* from the remote host and copies it to the [*dest*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-dest) at the remote host

```yaml
shell> ansible test_11 -m copy -a "src=/etc/passwd dest=/tmp/ansible/copy remote_src=true"
test_11 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true,
    "checksum": "2b1ed1b1cbe2a44c68148a61fed0812b9aa385fb",
    "dest": "/tmp/ansible/copy/passwd",
    "gid": 0,
    "group": "wheel",
    "md5sum": "f8ef74e8767c3692d622dd94ffde7000",
    "mode": "0644",
    "owner": "root",
    "size": 1888,
    "src": "/etc/passwd",
    "state": "file",
    "uid": 0
}
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls -la /tmp/ansible/copy
total 6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     3 Oct 16 06:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     3 Oct 16 06:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1888 Jan 11  2023 passwd

shell> ssh admin@test_11 md5 /tmp/ansible/copy/passwd
MD5 (/tmp/ansible/copy/passwd) = f8ef74e8767c3692d622dd94ffde7000
```

**fetch**

does also what it says. It fetches *src* from the remote host to the [*dest*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#parameter-dest) at the controller

```yaml
shell> ansible test_11 -m fetch -a "src=/etc/passwd dest=/tmp/ansible/fetch"
test_11 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true,
    "checksum": "2b1ed1b1cbe2a44c68148a61fed0812b9aa385fb",
    "dest": "/tmp/ansible/fetch/test_11/etc/passwd",
    "md5sum": "f8ef74e8767c3692d622dd94ffde7000",
    "remote_checksum": "2b1ed1b1cbe2a44c68148a61fed0812b9aa385fb",
    "remote_md5sum": null
}
```

```bash
shell> ls -la /tmp/ansible/fetch/test_11/etc/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 vlado vlado 4096 Oct 16 08:53 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 vlado vlado 4096 Oct 16 08:53 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vlado vlado 1888 Oct 16 08:53 passwd

shell> md5sum /tmp/ansible/fetch/test_11/etc/passwd 
f8ef74e8767c3692d622dd94ffde7000  /tmp/ansible/fetch/test_11/etc/passwd
```

Comment: so there is no way to copy directory directly? because `fetch` only works with files, and `synchronize` requires remote host has ability to ssh local machine. :(

Comment: IMHO *synchronize* doesn't require the remote host to ssh the local machine. I asked you to post mre including the expected result.